# How to increase the length limit of toString debugging tooltips in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

The tooltip when you move over a variable during Java debugging, only shows part of the result if the objects `toString` method returns a long string.

Is there an option to increase this limit?

`Settings -> Debugger -> Data Views` does not seem to help, as it includes only limits for arrays.

I'm using IDEA 12 Ultimate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no option to control the tooltip maximum length, you should use the **View Text** action from the variable context menu to inspect long values.